# Linux: Triggering Shell Command On File Save

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, inotify

I want to automatically trigger a shell command when a file is modified.  I think this can be accomplished in code by registering an inotify hook and call to `system`, however is there a higher level bash command that can accomplish this?

Comment: For an more portable and easier-to-debug alternative to [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait), check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10958125/1072112) to a very similar question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try inotify-tools.  I'm having problems copying the link (sorry), but there is a wiki on GitHub which yu should be able to find with G-search-engine.

Comment: you can use the inotifywait command to do this. See the example section in the inotifywait man page. http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait. I think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution to your problem, but I've found this nice program that you might use the feature you request: [cwatch](https://github.com/kse/cwatch)