# whether a shell script can be executed if another instance of the same script is already running

Tags: shell

I have a shell script which usually runs nearly 10 mins for a single run,but i need to know if another request for running the script comes while a instance of the script is running already, whether new request need to wait for existing instance to compplete or a new instance will be started.

I need a new instance must be started whenever a request is available for the same script.

How to do it...

The shell script is a polling script which looks for a file in a directory and execute the file.The execution of the file takes nearly 10 min or more.But during execution if a new file arrives, it also has to be executed simultaneously.

the shell script is below, and how to modify it to execute multiple requests..

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; do
 newfiles=`find /afs/rch/usr8/fsptools/WWW/cgi-bin/upload/ -newer /afs/rch/usr$
 touch /afs/rch/usr8/fsptools/WWW/cgi-bin/upload/.my_marker

 if [ -n "$newfiles" ]; then
   echo "found files $newfiles"
   name2=`ls /afs/rch/usr8/fsptools/WWW/cgi-bin/upload/ -Art |tail -n 2 |head $
    echo " $name2 "
     mkdir -p  -m 0755 /afs/rch/usr8/fsptools/WWW/dumpspace/$name2
     name1="/afs/rch/usr8/fsptools/WWW/dumpspace/fipsdumputils/fipsdumputil -e -$
  $name1
  touch /afs/rch/usr8/fsptools/WWW/dumpspace/tempfiles/$name2
   fi
   sleep 5
   done
```

Comment: Show the shell script maybe?

Comment: Thanks for adding the script. Obviously it doesn't work yet, but I also can't figure out what it's actually *for*. Things seems to get really wonky 6 lines from the bottom, where you assign `name1` without ever closing the quote. Was that a copy-and-paste error? Can you review and fix it, and explain the context for this script and what it's supposed to achieve?

Comment: Actually the script looks for new file in a directory and after that it has to create a new directory with the name of new file.The name1 is nothing but a calling a shell script named as fipsdumputil with aruguments, it nearly takes 10min to complete execution and during that time if any new file comes it also has to be executed ,how it can be done.

Comment: The fipsdumputil(name1) nearly takes 10 min to complete its execution, whether it can be separated from the current script  to a new script for it alone ,so that mulitple instance for new file can be made run.

Answer (score 2):

When writing scripts like the one you describe, I take one of two approaches.

First, you can use a pid file to indicate that a second copy should not run.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

pidfile=/var/run/$(0##*/).pid

# remove pid if we exit normally or are terminated
trap "rm -f $pidfile" 0 1 3 15

# Write the pid as a symlink
if ! ln -s "pid=$$" "$pidfile"; then
  echo "Already running. Exiting." >&2
  exit 0
fi

# Do your stuff
```

I like using symlinks to store pid because writing a symlink is an atomic operation; two processes can't conflict with each other. You don't even need to check for the existence of the pid symlink, because a failure of `ln` clearly indicates that a pid cannot be set. That's either a permission or path problem, or it's due to the symlink already being there.

Second option is to make it possible .. nay, preferable .. not to block additional instances, and instead configure whatever it is that this script does to permit multiple servers to run at the same time on different queue entries.  "*Single-queue-single-server*" is never as good as "*single-queue-multi-server*". Since you haven't included code in your question, I have no way to know whether this approach would be useful for you, but here's some explanatory meta bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

workdir=/var/tmp   # Set a better $workdir than this.

a=( $(get_list_of_queue_ids) )  # A command? A function? Up to you.

for qid in "${a[@]}"; do

  # Set a "lock" for this item .. or don't, and move on.
  if ! ln -s "pid=$$" $workdir/$qid.working; then
    continue
  fi

  # Do your stuff with just this $qid.
  ...

  # And finally, clean up after ourselves
  remove_qid_from_queue $qid
  rm $workdir/$qid.working

done
```

The effect of this is to transfer the idea of "one at a time" from the *handler* to the *data*.  If you have a multi-CPU system, you probably have enough capacity to handle multiple queue entries at the same time.

Comment: Actually I need to run multiple instance of same script with different data on requests. is it possible

Comment: Anything is possible. If you want help with your script, [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that includes the script. My second code sample above demonstrates how you might write something that can be run multiple times while clearing entries from the same queue.

Comment: I have added the script to the question, can you tell me how to modify it so that i can run multiple instances

Comment: Can you tell how to modify so that it can accept multiple requests at the same time

Comment: @DDK, I don't know enough about your environment to be able to recommend the "best" solution. But [here's an approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10958125/1072112) that I used to solve what might have been a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

[ghoti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35628176/45375) shows some helpful techniques, if modifying the script is an option.

Generally speaking, for an *existing* script:

Unless you know with certainty that:

- the script has no side effects other than to output to the terminal or to write to files with shell-instance specific names (such as incorporating `$$`, the current shell's PID, into filenames) or some other instance-specific location,
- OR that the script was explicitly designed for parallel execution,

I would assume that you *cannot* safely run multiple copies of the script simultaneously.

It is *not* reasonable to expect the average shell script to be designed for concurrent use.

Answer (score 0):

From the viewpoint of the operating system, several processes may of course execute the same program in parallel. No need to worry about this.

However, it *is* conceivable, that a (careless) programmer wrote the program in such a way that it produces incorrect results, when two copies are executed in parallel.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11404458)

Comment: @CindyMeister: I think it does answer the question. If I understood the question right, the OP wanted to know, whether a script can be run while another instance of the same script is already running. The answer is: From the viewpoint of the OS, it is possible. This is what I answered. Did I miss something?