# How to read a file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, readfile

I am new to shell scripting. I am trying to a script.

I have a log file, which saves the data every minute. The script needs to detect a keyword in that log file, if the keyword is present on it.

I was trying as below:

```
read jeeva/sample/logs.txt
grep keyword
```

I know my script is idiotic. Please help me with this.

Comment: generally, `grep keyword filename` is the accepted pattern for searching in files. Then becuase you're doing this every minute, you  might try `tail -f file | grep keyword`, but that is a fragile solution, suitable only for cmd-line use. Look for utilities designed to solve this problem, maybe `watcher` (there are numerous ones, it's not an easy problem to cover all the corner cases that appear in real life). Search here for `[bash] watch` for some ideas. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - I'm not so sure that `tail -f` (or at least `tail -F`) is so fragile. I provided [a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10958125/1072112) a while back that got some good response, based on something I've been running for years without problems.

Comment: @ghoti . Yep, I should have said "can be fragile" . I'll be sure to check for your answer! Tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you want to write it this way

```
$ if grep -q keyword jeeva/sample/logs.txt; 
  then echo "found"; 
  else echo "not found"; 
  fi
```

`-q` option is to suppress the output when the keyword is found.

Answer (score 3):

This will read a file into a variable

```
some_var=$(cat jeeva/sample/logs.txt)
```

But you don't need to do that. You only want to check for the word "keyword", so you can just

```
grep keyword jeeva/sample/logs.txt
```

In a script if that is found then `$?` will equal `0`, otherwise it will equal `1`.

So you can do:

```
grep keyword jeeva/sample/logs.txt
if ! [[ $? ]] 
then 
    echo found 
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: Using `$?` is a bit of an antipattern here. You can just do `if grep keyword jeeva/sample/logs.txt; then`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just need to monitor some tagged log messages.
How about:

```
tail -fn 1000 youFile.log | grep yourTag
```

Tail seems to be better in this case because you don't need to rerun it.

If you need script try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ $line == *"$2"* ]]; then
        echo "Do sth here.";
        echo "Like - I've found: $line";
    fi
done < "$1"
```

$1 is a file
$2 is your tag

```
➜  generated ./script.sh ~/apps/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/RUNNING.txt UNIX
Do sth here.
Like - I've found:     access to bind under UNIX.
```