# How to make fswatch run a shell script on file changes?

Tags: linux, macos, shell, watch

I have read the docs but I can not make it work as I expect.
I want to just launch a script when fswatch detects changes.
When I turn on verbose mode, I see in the logs that changes are detected:

```
notify_events: Notifying events #: 3.
```

I tried different variants but nothing seemed to work.
What if I just want to list some folder when changes occur, like this one?

```
fswatch -v ./src/**/*.go | ls ./src
```

Please share a working example just to know how to run a shell script.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how your changes occur, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10958125/1072112) might provide a satisfactory alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fswatch -v ./src/**/*.go | while IFS= read -r line
    ls ./src
done
```