# Bash awk append to same line

Tags: bash, awk

There are numerous posts about removing leading white space and appending an entry to a single existing line in a file using awk. None of my attempts work - just three examples here of the many I have tried.

Say I have a file called $log with a single line

`a:b:c`

and I want to add a fourth entry,

`awk '{ print $4"d" }' $log | tee -a $log`

output seems to be a newline

`a:b:c:

d`

whereas, I want all on the same line;

`a:b:c:d`

try

```
BEGIN { FS = ":" } ; awk '{ print $4"d" }' $log | tee -a $log
```

or, this - avoid a new line

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS=":" }; { print $4"d" }' $log | tee -a $log
```

no change

`a:b:c:

d`

awk is placing a space after `c:` and then writing `d` to the next line.

EDIT: | tee -a $log appears to be necessary to write the additional string to the file.

$log contains 39 variables and was generated using awk without | tee -a

odd...

The actual command to write $40 to the single line entries

```
awk '{ print $40"'$imagedir'" }' $log
```

output

```
+ awk '{ print $40"/home/geoland/Asterism-DEVEL/DSO" }' 

/home/geoland/.asterism/log
```

but this does not write to the $log file.

How should I append `d` to the same line without leading white space using awk - also looking at sed xargs and other alternatives.

Comment: It's not `awk` but `tee -a` that adds a new line

Comment: Get rid of the pipe to `tee -a $log` and you might understand awk much better but none of the commands you posted can produce the output you say they do so [edit] your question to show an actual command with actual output if you'd like help debugging whatever command it is you're actually executing.

Comment: Note that `$4` is empty; it looks like you should be using `print $0 ":d"`, but `print` adds a newline, so maybe you want `printf "%s:d", $0`.  And then the `tee -a` is odd, too; it's going to add the `a:b:c:d` after the end of the file.  Do you really have no newline at the end of the file?  Or would it matter whether you got a newline at the end of the file?

Comment: I have simplified the script for posting. However, the commands place 'd' on line 2 (gedit, line numbering) rather than immediately behind the last entry on line 1. I will find a way to post without drowning people in masses of detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

```
awk '{ print $0":d" }' file
```

Using [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
sed 's/$/:d/' file
```

Using only [`bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    echo "$line:d"
done < file
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with the bash solution slightly modified

Comment: @GeorgeC setting `IFS` like you did won't really change much :) also note that the `bash` solution is the slowest one and `awk` or `sed` are preferred for big files.

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around with the commands and get a better idea of what they do. Speed is not an issue and awk and sed need more research on my part. Not at all comfortable with either.

Comment: It would be really nice to hear the reason of someone's downvote. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: I usually sit on a problem until I find a solution. On this occasion, probably a low point of frustration, I asked the question without applying the first policy. The responses have been very helpful... I did the research and could make no sense of it........

Comment: @GeorgeC I **strongly** suggest checking those [sed and awk tutorials](http://www.grymoire.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
$ echo a:b:c | sed 's,\(^.*$\),\1:d,'
a:b:c:d
```

Comment: Why not simply `sed 's/$/:d/'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all... This is the solution I went with. I also needed to write the entire line to a perpetual log file because the log file is overwritten at each new process instance.

I will further investigate an awk solution.

```
logname=$imagedir/log_$name

while IFS=: read -r line; do 
    echo "$line$imagedir"
done < $log | tee $logname
```

This places $imagedir directly behind the last IFS ':' separator

There is probably room for refinement.

Answer (score 0):

I too am not entirely sure what you're trying to do here.

Your command line, `awk '{ print $4"d" }' $log | tee -a $log` is problematic in a number of ways.

First, your awk script tries to print the 4th field, which is empty. Unless you say otherwise, fields are separated by whitespace, and the string `a:b:c` has no whitespace.  So .. awk prints "d".  And `tee -a` appends to your existing logfile, so what you're seeing is the original data, along with the `d` printed by awk. That's totally expected.

Second, it appears to have `tee` appending to the same file that `awk` is in the process of reading. This won't make an endless loop, as `awk` should stop reading the input file after whatever was the last byte when the file was opened, but it does mean you may have repeated data there.

Your other attempts, aside from some syntactical errors, all suffer from the same assumption that `$4` means something that it does not.

The following awk snippet sets the input and output field separators to `:`, then sets the 4th field to "d", then prints the line.

```
$ echo "a:b:c" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$4="d"} 1'
a:b:c:d
```

Is that what you want?

If you really do need to append this data to an existing log file, you can do so with `tee -a` or simple `>>` redirection. Just bear in mind that awk will only see the content of the file as of the time it was run, and by appending, you are *not replacing* lines.

One other thing. If you are actually hoping to use the content of the shell variable `$imagedir` inside awk, you should pass the variable in rather than exiting your quotes. For example:

```
$ echo "a:b:c" | awk -v d="foo/bar" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$4=d} 1'
a:b:c:foo/bar
```

Comment: Thanks. The bash script runs a series of image manipulation tasks. The user ticks the boxes in the yad --form which populates the log file. All process variables are then read from the file. The log file is saved and used by another process, which needs to know which directory the target images are located.

Comment: ...the saved log file can be loaded and the image directory read directly, without reselecting the files.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like something I would do differently. Rather than treating the "log file" as a database which multiple processes might update (perhaps conflicting with each other?), you could have your user interface dump instructions to a log file that gets watched by an always-running process ... like `tail -f`. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10958125/1072112) from a few years ago for an idea of what I mean.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my implementation is clunky. It's a rigid step by step procedure. The saved log file is a means of passing variables to standalone scripts to avoid duplicating user entries when certain sub-processes are performed. In hindsight, the log file is not necessary for the main bash script. I need only save the bash variables.

Comment: I'll take a closer look at your suggestions.

Comment: If Asterism was on github, I might be interested in making the odd pull request. :)

Comment: Thanks. I have considered putting it on GitHub. There are two versions and I need to decide which is the better model. The process is perhaps overly rigid and I'm working at building in more flexibility. v2 is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s|$|$imagedir|" file | tee newfile
```

This does the trick. Read 'file' and write the contents of 'file' with the substitution to a 'new file', so as to read the image directory when using a secondary standalone process.

Because the variable is a directory with several / these need to be escaped, so as not to interpret as sed delimiters. I had difficulty with this using a variable.

A neater option was to use an alternative delimiter. Not to be confused with the pipe that follows.