# How to catch/write - success/failure logs for sFTP - PUT command

Tags: shell

In my shell script, after sFTP put process is completed. I need to check if the PUT process is completed successfully or failed.

Comment: Show some code. There's more than one sftp client, and right now we don't even know which one you're asking about. (Personally, btw, I'm a big fan of [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/), which is (1) supports a lot more protocols than just sftp -- also regular ftp, http, standard ssh, and many others; and (2) is designed with scripting in mind).

Comment: (Also, the arguments you're using matter rather a lot -- OpenSSH's `sftp` will behave quite differently with a list of commands passed to stdin via a heredoc or expect script vs the `-b` batchfile option).

Comment: spawn  sftp user@hostname
expect  "password:"                    
send "$PWD\r";
expect "sftp> "
send "put test_file.txt  <DEST_LOCATION>.*\r";
expect "sftp> "
send "bye\r";

Comment: I need to verify if the -> sFTP put completed successfully or not. could you please let me know, the process to check this condition.

Comment: [Edit] the code into the question, don't add it as a comment.

Comment: That said, it looks like you're using `expect`. **Don't.** Use `sftp -b` with a script containing the commands, which will cause `sftp` to exit with a failed exit status if any operation fails.

Comment: Thank you. For reference, could you please provide me sample code to write/catch the sFTP - PUT process log.

Comment: You don't need the log if you just need to know if it succeeded or failed -- as long as you're using the batchfile option, all you need to do is check the exit status.

Comment: expect "sftp>"
       send "bye\n"
       interact
       if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
         echo "sFTP success"
       else   echo "fail"                                                                                                   
       fi                                                                                                                       Correct ?

Comment: No, because you aren't using `batchfile`, and sftp is only documented to reflect success in exit status in batchfile mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a shell command when a file is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956668/run-a-shell-command-when-a-file-is-added)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use `expect` at all.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

batchfile=$(mktemp -t sftp-batchfile.XXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$batchfile"' EXIT

cat >"$batchfile" <EOF
put test_file.txt $dest_location
bye
EOF

if sftp -b "$batchfile" "user@hostname"; then
  echo "The put succeeded"
else
  echo "The put failed"
fi
```

---

As given in the SFTP man page, with emphasis added:

> The final usage format allows for automated sessions using the -b option.  **In such cases, it is necessary to configure non-interactive authentication to obviate the need to enter a password at connection time** (see sshd(8) and ssh-keygen(1) for details).