# How do I use OSX's Folder Actions to execute a command in Terminal when a file is added to a folder?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, directory

How do I use OSX's Folder Actions to execute a command in Terminal when a file is added to a folder? My understanding is that Folder Actions can trigger AppleScripts when files are placed in them. I tried to modify a sample "added to folder" script, but it's not working.

This is the exact Terminal command I'd like to run on any zip files placed in the folder (and I know this syntax is correct):

```
for file in *.zip; do zip -d "$file" "__MACOSX*"; done; for file in *.zip; do zip -d "$file" "*.DS_Store"; done; unzip -l \*.zip
```

I tried this code in Script Editor (ver. 2.10), but it's not correct syntax:

```
on adding folder items to theAttachedFolder after receiving theNewItems
    tell application Terminal
        for file in *.zip; do zip -d "$file" "__MACOSX*"; done; for file in *.zip; do zip -d "$file" "*.DS_Store"; done; unzip -l \*.zip 
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Here is what the script looks like in Script Editor if that helps any:

[image]

What is the correct syntax? I'm running OSX 10.13.6.

PS: I've seen [Run a shell command when a file is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956668/run-a-shell-command-when-a-file-is-added) plus several other similar questions, but I'm too new to Folder Actions and AppleScripts to understand how to make them work in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the syntax:

```
set currentTab to do script ("[command]")
```

For example:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set currentTab to do script ("ls")
end tell
```

Would list the current directory. Make sure you also wrap Terminal in quotes: "Terminal"

Comment: Actually, that does work for "ls", but for the long command string I was wanting to use, it doesn't work. At the first $ it says "Syntax Error: Expected “,” but found unknown token." Also, is there any syntax manual I can look at? What would I google to find it? I can't find anything so far.

Comment: Instead of trying to use Terminal, just use the 'do shell script' instruction in your Applescript. It runs a shell command directly from AS. Because it seems your folder is always the same, you can hardcode this folder path into your shell command. Currently, you zip command does not specify the folder containing the .zip. Keep in mind that AS, then 'do shell script' do not know what default folder means.